# Changing the live activity without push notification

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement "Live activity" to my app. I am following the Apple docs.

Link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/displaying-live-data-with-live-activities

Example code:

```
struct LockScreenLiveActivityView: View {
    let context: ActivityViewContext<PizzaDeliveryAttributes>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("\(context.state.driverName) is on their way with your pizza!")
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Label {
                    Text("\(context.attributes.numberOfPizzas) Pizzas")
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "bag")
                        .foregroundColor(.indigo)
                }
                .font(.title2)
                Spacer()
                Label {
                    Text(timerInterval: context.state.deliveryTimer, countsDown: true)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .frame(width: 50)
                        .monospacedDigit()
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "timer")
                        .foregroundColor(.indigo)
                }
                .font(.title2)
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .activitySystemActionForegroundColor(.indigo)
        .activityBackgroundTint(.cyan)
    }
}
```

Actually, the code is pretty straightforward. We can use the `timerInterval` for count-down animation. But when the timer ends, I want to update the Live Activity view. If the user re-opens the app, I can update it, but what happens if the user doesn't open the app? Is there a way to update the live activity without using push notifications?

Answer (score -4):

NO. Live activity only can be updated/ended by ActivityKit or remote push notification. So if the user doesn't open the app, just update live activity by remote push notification.

Comment: Why is this answer voted down when there are no other answers? Is this answer correct and the answer being voted down because people don't like it? Or is is incorrect?